# Converting DateTime stamps into unix with Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I can't seem to get a time stamp into a unix timestamp format and assume I'm missing some points. Looking for some help.

I have a column within a df that is a datetime object in the format:
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and I need a new column with the unix stamp.

I'm bringing the csv into python with:

```
gps = filepath here   
dateparse= lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
gps_dat = pd.read_csv(gps, parse_dates=['date_stamp'],date_parser=dateparse)
```

Anytime I try to change this column into a unix stamp I'm getting an error about wrong format or "datetime.datetime" has no attribute "datetime" with this:

```
gps_dat['unix']=datetime.datetime(gps_dat['date_stamp'])
```

Should I be using

```
calendar.timegm(tuple)
```

I'm still learning so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you probably imported `datetime.datetime` instead of just `datetime`, so when you call `datetime.datetime` you're really calling `datetime.datetime.datetime`, which isn't defined. Sorry to sound a bit like Xzibit, but... :)

Comment: I think that definitely fixed part of the problem thanks! When I use the:
     gps_dat['unix']=datetime.datetime(gps_dat['date_stamp'])

Now I get error "cannot convert the series to <class 'int>"

Comment: what does `gps_dat['date_stamp']` look like?

Comment: gps_dat['date_stamp'] is a column within my dataframe:
 2015-04-16 15:23:20

Comment: I mean, is it already a `datetime` object, or is it a string? If it's already a `datetime` object, you just need to use `gps_dat['unix'] = gps_dat['date_stamp']`. If it's a string instead, use `gps_dat['unix'] = datetime.strptime(gps_dat['date_stamp'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: It's a datetime object but I need it as a unix timestamp.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer with a potential fix, but I don't know Pandas, so YMMV. Hopefully, somebody who's used Pandas will show up!

Comment: @MB_analyst, please post an output of `gps_dat.dtypes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** if you want to convert datetime column **to** UNIX timestamp:

```
gps_dat['unix']=gps_dat['date_stamp'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
```

NOTE: but it must be of `datetime` type, **not** string/object

**Old answer:** parsing **from** UNIX timestamp to datetime

try to change your parser function like this:

```
dateparse= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s')
```

this will instruct [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) that you're using UNIX timestamp format

Comment: When I parse with this function I'm still getting: 2015-04-21 23:32:25 format.

Comment: THIS WORKED!! Thanks to everyone for their input. It's very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use faster solution with `list` comprehension:

```
print gps_dat
  nam  code date1          date_stamp
0   a     1   1/1 2012-10-08 18:15:05
1   b     3   3/4 2012-10-08 18:15:05

gps_dat['unix'] = [t.value // 10 ** 9 for t in gps_dat['date_stamp']]
print gps_dat
  nam  code date1          date_stamp        unix
0   a     1   1/1 2012-10-08 18:15:05  1349720105
1   b     3   3/4 2012-10-08 18:15:05  1349720105
```

**Timings**:

```
In [46]: %timeit gps_dat['date_stamp'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
1000 loops, best of 3: 204 µs per loop

In [47]: %timeit [t.value // 10 ** 9 for t in gps_dat['date_stamp']]
The slowest run took 4.99 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.2 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I've never used Pandas, but it looks like this is the kind of function that you should call:

```
gps_dat['unix'] = gps_dat.apply(lambda row: time.mktime(row['date_stamp'].timetuple()), axis=col_number)
```

where `col_number` is the index of your `date_stamp` column (assuming it was correctly parsed as a `datetime`).

**Original answer** (when I didn't know Pandas was involved):

Replace that

```
gps_dat['unix']=datetime.datetime(gps_dat['date_stamp'])
```

line with

```
gps_dat['unix'] = time.mktime(gps_dat['date_stamp'].timetuple())
```

And add

```
import time
```

to your imports. Note that [some considerations apply to time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/1159164), so according to your requirements you might want to add some logic to, say, convert to UTC.

Comment: I got: " 'Series object has no attribute 'timetuple' "

Comment: ok so that's a [pandas.Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), not a `datetime`. I added a `pandas` tag so that people familiar with the library can help.

You might want to check what `gps_dat['date_stamp'].data` contains by printing it out

Comment: Using this I'm getting a "unhashable type:list" error. Thanks for all your help, by the way.